# FastAPI integration with KeyCloak OpenID

Tags: authentication, keycloak, fastapi

I am trying to integrate `keycloak` to my current `fastAPI` application for user authentication and authorization. I already set-up a realm, a `OpenID` client with `standard flow` and `direct access grants` and created some basics users with a password credential.

[image: set-up]

On my FastAPI application, I am using the KeyCloackOpenID library to communicate with KeyCloack. I created 2 endpoints,

1. `/token`: used for login, the user is asked to put his keycloack username and password.
2. `/logout`: for logout

[image]

For the `/token`, when my `username` and `password` are correct, I am able to get my access token and other informations such as refresh token. But how can I make a real login endpoint instead of just a endpoint to get a token? It seems that I must used something like `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer` based on what I have read on [that FastAPI issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1428). At the endpoint, I would like to add **protected routes** where only authenticated users can access without having to submit a form everytime.

I have the same problem with the `logout` endpoint, I am able to "logout" but I still need to type my `username` and `password` on the `/logout` endpoint even if I just called the login endpoint with a `200` response code
[image]

My code:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import (
    OAuth2PasswordBearer,
    OAuth2PasswordRequestForm,
    OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer,
)
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

auth_router = auth = APIRouter()

keycloak_url = "http://localhost:8080"
realm_name = "dive-dev"
client_id = "quarkus-be"
client_secret = "74vIzXHvrI5Mnsb15LYYQo4nmMutD3g3"

keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url=keycloak_url,
    realm_name=realm_name,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret_key=client_secret,
)

# not used yet
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl=f"http://localhost:8080/realms/dive-dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    tokenUrl="http://localhost:8080/realms/dive-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token",
)


async def get_tokens(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    try:
        token_response = keycloak_openid.token(
            username=form_data.username,
            password=form_data.password,
            grant_type="password",
        )
        return token_response
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Login failed") from e


def get_current_tokens(tokens: dict = Depends(get_tokens)):
    return tokens


@auth.post("/token", response_model=dict)
async def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    tokens = await get_tokens(form_data)
    # Store the access and refresh tokens in a dependency for later use
    return {
        "access_token": tokens["access_token"],
        "refresh_token": tokens["refresh_token"],
        "user_info": keycloak_openid.userinfo(tokens["access_token"]),
    }


@auth.post("/logout")
async def logout(tokens: dict = Depends(get_current_tokens)):
    try:
        refresh_token = tokens.get("refresh_token")
        if not refresh_token:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Refresh token not found")
        keycloak_openid.logout(refresh_token=refresh_token)
        return {"message": "Logged out successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Logout failed") from e
```

Comment: Am I understand you correctly? You want to have a button in Swagger interface, wich you can use to authorize using UserName and Password, and then make requests on protected endpoints via Swagger.

Comment: Yes, I am also not sure how should i create secured endpoint using KeyCloak I guess I would have to use the oauth2_scheme somewhere as well as select "OAuth2"on my KeyCloak client settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it, but maybe it will be helpful for you:

1. If you want to allow users to authorize with UserName and Password, you should use `OAuth2PasswordBearer` instead of `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer`:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
```

2. Your `login` endpoint looks correct. You should get UserName and Password Form fields and return tokens.

The only one moment here: in the FastAPI documentation it's recommended to return token type `return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}`

3. In your `logout` endpoint and in other protected endpoints you shouldn't use `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` as a dependency. You should use `oauth2_scheme` instead.

You should change your `get_tokens` function to something like this:

```
@auth.post("/logout")
async def logout(access_token: dict = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    # Here you need somehow get the refresh token having access token.
    # As I understand, Swagger will not store and send refresh token to your endpoints.
    try:
        keycloak_openid.logout(refresh_token)
    ...
```

Implementing this you will get green "Authorize" button wtich works as you expect.

In general, I would recommend that you start by implementing the [example from FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) and then adapt it to work with keycloak.

You can also have a look at [fastapi-keycloak](https://fastapi-keycloak.code-specialist.com/full_example/) library. It seems that this one is simpler to use with FastAPI.

Comment: Thank you Yuri for your pertinent and complete. I did try the fastapi_keycloak library but it seems there are currently a couple of severe bugs. What were you thinking to put inside the get_tokens  function?

Comment: As I understand, your `get_tokens` function works (you said that you can authorize via login endpoint and get tokens). The main question for me is how to get refresh_token to perform `logout`. Because, as I understand, In this implementation Swagger will not send it to your endpoint. And I don't know how to make Swagger do send it. I guess you should find another authentication scheme (not OAuth2PasswordBearer) that works with refresh tokens. But I'm not sure it exists (I didn't manage to find it. It seems like it's not implemented yet).